# using apn_sender on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, apple-push-notifications, resque

We built an api in rails and are hosting it on heroku and using apn_sender to do the push notifications.  We got everything running locally with apn_sender but when we push it to heroku and run

```
heroku rake apn:sender
```

we get the following error "Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379"

We added the redistogo addon.

**UPDATE**

We added a resque.rb initializer:

```
require 'resque'

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

and called to start up the worker

```
heroku rake environment apn:sender
```

and everything seemed to work.

Comment: Did you configure the addon as well as documented on this [Heroku help page](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo)?

Comment: Please can you tell me which guide did you follow to accomplish this?

Comment: Followed what was on the heroku help page.  It seems like it should just work at this point.  Not sure why apn is trying to connect to redis at 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Please Scott, can you tell me how you did it? It would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after further testing, the update I put in above doesn't work for very long before it crashes.  We then followed this http://blog.redistogo.com/2010/07/26/resque-with-redis-to-go/

Changing

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end
```

to

```
task "apn:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end
```

and

```
desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

to

```
desc "Alias for apn:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "apn:work"
```

and it worked like a charm.  Also note, that we had to add a worker dyno in heroku, which costs .05/hour or $35/month.

Comment: I was able to get this solution working, but I also need to use resque for other background tasks. Having trouble configuring things so apn_sender works while keeping resque working in general.